# Image not showing from CGImageCreateWithImageInRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

My image will not display and I've tried other images as well, I just get a blank screen.

```
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"building-demolition4.gif"];
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([img CGImage], CGRectMake(0, 0, 208.5, 119));
UIImageView *ckImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 208.5, 119)];
ckImage.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
[self.view addSubview:ckImage];
```

Comment: Is `img` nil? Use logging to find out.

Comment: In fact, step thru the code in the debugger to see whether decent values are being assigned at each line.

Comment: Okay let me do that I'll report back in a minute, sorry new to programming will take me a second

Comment: On the first line img has an address, on the second line img becomes nil. Why would that be?

Comment: Where is this image supposed to be? Saying `[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"building-demolition4.gif"]` doesn't exactly say where to look for the file.

Comment: I added it to xcode, I had that same line working in other code so I know the image loading is working, and one the first line img has an address after being run so that line must be working. Somehow the second line is reverting img back to nil but I don't know the ins and outs so I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `initWithContentsOfFile:` requires a file path. `@"building-demolition4.gif"` is not a file path - it's just a bare name. So the runtime does not know where to look for the file - and is thus failing to find it.

If this image is inside your app bundle (because it was part of your project), the simple way to access it is with the UIImage class method `imageNamed:`.

(The more complex way is to get the path to the image with the NSBundle method `pathForResource:...`, but there is really no need for that here.)

Comment: Because `imageNamed:` looks inside your app, automatically. `initWithContentsOfFile:` doesn't know where to look until you tell it, and you are not telling it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used following code which works for me:

```
NSString *fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myimg" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
CGImageRef cgimg = image.CGImage;
UIImageView *imgview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
[imgview setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg]];
[self.view addSubview:imgview];
```

if you want to add gif file have look to following link might help you.

https://github.com/unixpickle/Giraffe